# How to extract certain Data that appears after certain keyword from .txt file

Tags: python

I have results from my experiment stored in .txt file. Here is the sample of the output.txt

```
Initializing the time of all nodes on network 10.0.0.0 to: 0.0
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
Run Experiment:

Start LTG Traffice  AP -> STA
START TIME:2015-10-28 09:17:55.460000

Stop  LTG - AP -> STA
 ....Removing LTG+Saving and Writing Logs file after 0.3 s
END TIME:2015-10-28 09:18:25.467000

Log Sizes:  AP  = 14,155,896 bytes
            STA = 26,162,648 bytes

Initializing the time of all nodes on network 10.0.0.0 to: 0.0
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
Run Experiment:

Start LTG Traffice  AP -> STA
START TIME:2015-10-28 09:20:32.499000

Stop  LTG - AP -> STA
 ....Removing LTG+Saving and Writing Logs file after 0.3 s
END TIME:2015-10-28 09:21:02.505000

Log Sizes:  AP  = 14,152,304 bytes
            STA = 26,163,856 bytes
Initializing the time of all nodes on network 10.0.0.0 to: 0.0
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
Run Experiment:

Start LTG Traffice  AP -> STA
START TIME:2015-10-28 09:23:09.512000

Stop  LTG - AP -> STA
 ....Removing LTG+Saving and Writing Logs file after 0.3 s
END TIME:2015-10-28 09:23:39.518000

Log Sizes:  AP  = 12,144,180 bytes
            STA = 22,720,608 bytes
```

After every experiment, following output from python script is printed in the output.txt which always has following information:

```
Initializing the time of all nodes on network 10.0.0.0 to: 0.0
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
Run Experiment:

Start LTG Traffice  AP -> STA
START TIME:2015-10-28 09:23:09.512000

Stop  LTG - AP -> STA
 ....Removing LTG+Saving and Writing Logs file after 0.3 s
END TIME:2015-10-28 09:23:39.518000

Log Sizes:  AP  = 12,144,180 bytes
            STA = 22,720,608 bytes
```

How can i extract the START TIME information and store in new.txt like:

```
2015-10-28 09:17:55.460000
2015-10-28 09:20:32.499000
2015-10-28 09:23:09.512000
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My try as below- based on regular expression.

```
import re

f = open(r"C:\log.txt",'rb')

pattern = re.findall(r'(?<=START TIME:)([0-9-:\s.]+)$',f.read(),re.M|re.I)
for i in pattern:
    print i.strip()
```

It prints

```
2015-10-28 09:17:55.460000
2015-10-28 09:20:32.499000
2015-10-28 09:23:09.512000
```

---

### Explanation of regular expression

### (?<=START TIME:)([0-9-:\s.]+)$

```
(?<=START TIME:)([0-9-:\s.]+)$
```

Options: Case insensitive; Exact spacing; Dot doesn't match line breaks; ^$ match at line breaks; Regex syntax only

- Assert that the regex below can be matched, with the match ending at this position (positive lookbehind) `(?<=START TIME:)`

  - Match the character string “START TIME:” literally (case insensitive) `START TIME:`
- Match the regex below and capture its match into backreference number 1 `([0-9-:\s.]+)`

  - Match a single character present in the list below `[0-9-:\s.]+`

    - Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) `+`
    - A character in the range between “0” and “9” `0-9`
    - A single character from the list “-:” `-:`
    - A “whitespace character” (any Unicode separator, tab, line feed, carriage return, vertical tab, form feed, next line) `\s`
    - The literal character “.” `.`
- Assert position at the end of a line (at the end of the string or before a line break character) (line feed) `$`

---

EDIT

to get upto two decimal try below

```
import re

f = open(r"C:\Users\Winrock\Desktop\log.txt",'rb')

pattern = re.findall(r'(?<=START TIME:)([0-9-:\s.]+)$',f.read(),re.M|re.I)
for i in pattern:
    data = i.strip()
    print data [0:len(data)-4]
```

Comment: Is it possible to extract the timestamp only till 2 points after decimal eg.2015-10-28 09:17:55.46

Answer (score 1):

This code can get you the result:

```
fout = open('new.txt', 'w')
for line in open('output.txt', 'r'):
    if line.startswith('START TIME'):
        fout.write("%s\n" % line.split('START TIME:')[1].strip())
```

Comment: This implementation using only position 1 of `strip()` will not print out the minutes, seconds, and milliseconds following the 2nd colon.  I tried this too initially ;)  To do it with `split()`, try `''.join(line.split(':')[1:]).strip()`

Comment: thats why line.split('START TIME:')[1].strip() and not line.split(':')[1].strip()

Answer (score 0):

I like the answer by @SIslam.

Here's an alternative implementation using [`str.partition`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.partition):

**extractstarttime.py:**

```
with open('experiment.log', 'rU') as efile:
    with open('starttimes.log', 'a') as sfile:
        for line in efile:
            if line.startswith('START TIME:'):
                starttime = line.partition(':')[2].strip()
                sfile.write(starttime+'\n')
```

**Output:**

```
$ python extractstarttime.py
$ cat starttimes.log
2015-10-28 09:17:55.460000
2015-10-28 09:20:32.499000
2015-10-28 09:23:09.512000
```